# Grid View items become invisible when scroll down

Tags: android

1.i have a grid view in which i have to get image path from database and images are in drawable
my issue is when i scroll down grid view images becomes invisible i have the following adapater
2.any help????

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    List<Fotota> list_popupBarBackGround;
    static final int ON_STICKER_LAYOUT=4;

    private static ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Fotota> list_popupBarBackGround) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list_popupBarBackGround = list_popupBarBackGround;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return list_popupBarBackGround.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;  
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_griditem, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


    convertView.setTag(holder);

   } else {

   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }              


 holder.imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources()
.getIdentifier(list_popupBarBackGround.get(position).getThumbnail(),     "drawable",context.getPackageName()));


   return convertView;
   }

   private static class ViewHolder {
   ImageView imageView;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the position in your `getItem()`.

Also remove the two instance of your `ViewHolder()` in your `getView()` method. Just declare it once only.

> ```
>   @Override
>    public Object getItem(int position) {
>     return list_popupBarBackGround.get(position);
>   }
>   @Override
>   public long getItemId(int position) {
>       return position;  
>   }
> ```

Comment: by doing this nothing happened .when i give fix size to imageview items does not disappear but i need "wrap contant" the images

Comment: no i have to give imageview wrap contant but on setting imageview as wrap contant view disapears.problem is still here

Comment: Have you written anything for the `GridView` onScroll event ?

Answer (score 0):

Override this two methods in adapter

```
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list_popupBarBackGround.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;  
    }
```

Comment: by doing this nothing happened .when i give fix size to imageview items does not disappear but i need "wrap contant" the images

Comment: please set minHeight for image layout and try. please let me know if it's working.

Answer (score -1):

use Recyclerview instead of Gridview.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```